# Can / Be able to , Is there any difference or the same?

Tags: grammar

I can play football very well

I'm able to play football very well

Can you come to my party tonight?

Are you able to come to my party tonight?

Comment: Can you come to my party tonight? I don't know, can I!?

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your examples, they mean the same.

Just note that we sometimes use 'can' to make a polite, immediate request, for example "*can you leave your shoes at the door?*". We wouldn't ask, in that situation, "*are you able to take off your shoes*" as it sounds a little condescending or possibly even passive-aggressive. But no reasonable person demands others come to a party, which is why in your context there is no difference.

Comment: I was tempted to also make the the distinction between "can" and "will" in my answer. "Can" asks the possibility of an action whilst "will" requests that action be taken. So maybe, if you want to protect your new carpet, you might say *"Will you please leave your shoes by the door?"*

Answer (score 0):

"can you" and "are you able to" have the same meaning, so your two pairs of sentences also mean the same, both as statements and questions. But I think this question has been asked before.